# Allow user to add files to a folder, without allowing them to change files once they are in the folder?

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I want something similar to the following:

There is a folder, lets call it 'Parent'.

I want people to be able to add files into Parent, but I do not want them to be able to view/read/write files that are in Parent.

Example:

User has a zip file. They are able to place that zip file into Parent. However, they cannot view, read, nor write any files that are already in Parent. Furthermore, once they move the zip file to Parent, that file is also now inaccessible to them.

I'd like to know if this is possible within windows, without having to do anything *too* fancy. I could accomplish this by allowing the user to have read/write access to Parent, but stripping all them of all privileges to the files within Parent. The only real question is how do I do this automatically.

Comment: If they cannot view the contents of Parents, then they don't have the permissions, to put files into Parents.  If you require this workflow I suggest you have a single person in charge of putting files into the folder.

Answer (score 2):

Run `cmd` as Administrator, then perform the command

```
icacls "...\Parent" /grant UserOrGroup:(OI)(CI)(S,WD)
```

`UserOrGroup` - user or group name

`(OI)(CI)` means - this folder, subfolders, and files.

`(S,WD)` means - only Synchronize + Write data/add file.

But if a there is a file, say `f1.txt`, in the folder `Parent` and a user tries to copy another file with the same name (`f1.txt`) system will show a warning message like "You should have a permissions ... to copy to this folder". So a user can detect that the file `f1.txt` exists in the folder `Parent`.

**Update**

The script

```
rem  Create a folder
md "Parent"

rem  Disable ACL inheritance
icacls "Parent" /inheritance:d

rem  Remove all default permissions for Username
icacls "Parent" /remove:g Username

rem  Grant restricted permissions for Username
icacls "Parent" /grant Username:(OI)(CI)(S,WD)
```

Comment: Have you tested this with the User Interface? I suspect that the user can't grab a file and paste to the folder. It may work only for a program running as the user.

Comment: Yes I did. Does not it working for you?

Comment: I've tested yesterday and it did not work. But instead of using `icacls`, I've used the User Interface to change the permissions (disabling inheritance, removing all permissions and granting only Write). Maybe its working for you due to this `Synchronize` grant that is not available at the UI.